# What is the reaction force if i push my leg downward in deep space or on a friction less surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

As per newtons law,for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

Consider first situation,if i exert a force on a friction less surface,what is the reaction force?

What will be the reaction force when i push my leg downward in deep space? Since space cant push me back,can such forces considered as actions?

(I think both situations are similar)
(I am getting sleeplessness thinking about it,help me!!!)

Comment: Can you draw a free body diagram about it?

Comment: Your expression of N3L is not very precise. It specifically deals with forces.

Comment: If you are floating in space you can actually make your body turn by moving your arms for example. If you move your leg your body will move slightly in the opposite direction. If you clap your hands together you don't move because the 2 starting forces oppose each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a frictionless surface, the reaction force will always be perpendicular to the surface. You cannot exert a lateral (sliding) force on a frictionless surface, and therefore there can be no lateral (sliding) reaction force, either.

Saying that "you push your leg down" in deep space is a highly misleading way of phrasing the action that's happening. Rather than "you," it's a certain *part* of you, namely your leg muscles, that is exerting a force against other parts of you. Rather than "pushing your leg down," it's actually *rotating* your leg via the joints in your hip and knee. When your muscles exert a force to rotate your legs, the reaction force is the normal force coming from your bones, ligaments, and tendons, namely, the pieces of your body that don't allow your muscles to simply pass through your legs. This has the effect of redistributing your weight, which may cause some other parts of your body to shift relative to where they once were, but your center of mass will always remain in the same place.

Comment: Classy answer,thats why i like this site.

Answer (score 1):

Per Newton’s Third Law all forces occur in equal and oppositely directed pairs.

In your first example the surface exerts a force of equal magnitude but opposite direction to the force you exert on it. That reaction force is an external force as far as your body is concerned.

In the second example there is no external forces to react to you moving your leg downward in space. The force you exert in moving your leg downward is an internal force.  Consider your body as an isolated system in space.  An internal force on one part of your body is countered by an internal reaction force on another part of your body. An isolated system can’t exert a net force on itself. In order for you to accelerate you must interact with an object external to yourself.

Hope this helps.